# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am getting the error
 "**TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**"
while using vuex-persistedstate plugin.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

I had found some solution to use plugin with no error as below

```
plugins: [createPersistedState]
```

But it is not saving the state details.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't mentioned where you want to store the data. Since I am storing vuex data in localStorage my code goes something like:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
   // ...
   plugins: [createPersistedState(
     storage: window.localStorage
   )]
 })
```

So basically, just pass **storage: window.localStorage** to your **createPersistedState()** method.

Enjoy!